# How to restrict browser back button after success page magento

Tags: magento-1.9

how to restrict browser back button in success page 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better try this in your success page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    window.location.href("http://www.yourhomepageurl.com/");
});
</script>
```

Source from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526811/change-the-back-button-url-in-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function disableBack() { window.history.forward() }

        window.onload = disableBack();
        window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBack() }
    });
</script>
```

I got this from here: http://www.encodedna.com/2014/07/restrict-or-disable-browser-back-button-using-javascript.htm

Keep in mind though that this should not be needed in Magento. When your order is made in the checkout, a hit on the back button (or backspace) should lead to the shopping cart, which in turn should no longer have a quote, and therefore should say that there are no items and redirect to the homepage, it should not be possible to make the same order twice for example.

Comment: In my case i am not placing any order.I am sending quotation form.So after coming to success page(Screen shot)when i click on browser back button its going to quotation form again. It should not happen.I want redirect to home page.